# Embeding Checkbox to a specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm current working with VBA which is quite new for me. I'am trying to embeeded my checkbox into it specific cells so that each time the cells (row) is hidden, the checkbox will be hidden also with the cell.

below is the code I'm currently using to insert the Checkbox

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Cells(lRow, "A").Left, _
                            Cells(lRow, "A").Top, _
                            72, 17.25).Select
With Selection
    .Caption = ""
    .Value = xlOff
    .LinkedCell = "C" & i
    .Display3DShading = False

End With
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Does your code errors out? Please elaborate.

Comment: the code doesn't error out. but each time I hide the row, the checkbox will remain unhide. u can still see and tick the checkbox. is there a way to embed the checkbox to the cell, so that it will hide together with the cell.?

Comment: Are you just looking for the [Cell Link](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2042382/add-checkboxes-to-an-excel-spreadsheet.html) property of the checkbox?

Comment: Matt: nope.. I'm not referring to the Cell Link properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, I don't think so. 
There's also no known *Event* to trap hiding and un-hiding of rows (again AFAIK).
The closest I can give is something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Set cb = Me.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object
    cb.Top = Me.Range("cbrange").Top
    cb.Visible = IIf(Me.Range("cbrange").Height = 0, False, True)
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

This doesn't automatically hides the *Checkbox*, not until you select another range.
Take note that we used a named range which is the range that contains your *Checkbox*.
This is to make sure that the *Checkbox* stays with that cell even if the you insert rows. HTH somehow.